Typing Fractions in Wolfram Cloud
Apologies if this is the wrong place, but this (minor) QoL issue is really bugging me and I can't find an answer anywhere.
When using the desktop version of Mathematica, I can enter the fraction $\frac{x}{y}$ by typing x [CTRL] + \ y and it automatically formats it beautifully. Similarly for subscripts and superscript. When I use the online, in-browser editor of wolframcloud, this doesn't work. I tried a few different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera) and either nothing happened with [CTRL] + [key] or it activated some browser shortcut like changing the zoom level.
Is there a solution to this? Some alternative way of typing in formated fractions or super/sub- script? I know it's not a critical issue, but having legible code makes a world of difference in catching bugs and speed of progress.
(As an aside, what does work is typing in special characters using escape, so that [ESC]p[ESC] gives $\pi$. It's the use of [CTRL] that seems to be the problem.)

Keyboard shortcuts are a painful thing to implement well in a web browser. The web browser has its own set and its own system for capturing them etc. Most of the desktop shortcuts aren't supported because of this.
Look at the Insert Menu. Specifically TeX style input and Inline Input-Based Input. The Tex style input shortcut works for me on my instance of chrome, so I often use it to type "\frac{a}{b}" and such. The Inline Input keyboard short cut doesn't work for m e because it gets caught by the browser, but I think that's fixable. When I click that I can enter literally 1/x and it will format nicely in the input.

Works for me, thanks! Ironically, the [CTRL]+4 and [CTRL]+[SHFT]+1 keyboard shortcuts to get nice forming do work, despite the very similar keyboard short cuts that they replace not working.
